# Is there an ipad app to manage photo and video on external storage?

Tags: ipad, photos

I need an app to quickly browse through my photo and video on external drive. Due to number of photos and videos I have on external storage, I don't want to import it to Photos app first, instead I want to manage/browse directly from external drive.

The features I'm looking for:

- Browse
- Quick delete
- Auto grouping by month/year
- AI tagging??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Apple `Files`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481) app to browse and delete files on an external drive. Manual tagging is also possible if file system of the external drive is HFS+ or APFS. *Auto Grouping* is not possible but it can automatically list the files by *Name*, *Size*, *Date* or *Tags* in ascending or descending order.

(Note that the `Files` app will do all the actions directly on the files in the external drive, without needing to import the files unnecessarily to your device).